# Sending empty class to generic class as default parameter in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `QueryFilter<TSearchFilter>` class (see below). And I created a `QueryFilter` class that inherits from this class. I'm currently using the `QueryFilter` without specifying the type, like this:

```
var queryFilter = new QueryFilter();
```

To do this, I created a fake `EmptySearchFilter` class for achieving this. This works perfectly; no problem.

```
public class QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> where TSearchFilter : class
{
    public QueryFilter()
    {
        SearchFilter = (TSearchFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSearchFilter));
    }
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public int PageFirstIndex { get; set; }
    public byte PageSize { get; set; }
    public TSearchFilter SearchFilter { get; set; }
}

public class QueryFilter : QueryFilter<EmptySearchFilter> { }

public class EmptySearchFilter { }
```

But, I think that there's probably a way to avoid using this fake class (`EmptySearchFilter`) by doing something like:

```
public class QueryFilter : QueryFilter<typeof(Class)>{ }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Most times with a pair of generic/non-generic types that are for the same concept, the non-generic is the base class, the generic derived. But not knowing how these types are *used* makes it difficult to offer any *concrete* advice.

Comment: I think, you want to say like in @ZoharPeled's answer. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the inheritance chain like this:

```
public class QueryFilter 
{ 
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public int PageFirstIndex { get; set; }
    public byte PageSize { get; set; }
}

public class QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> : QueryFilter 
    where TSearchFilter : class, new() 
{
    public QueryFilter()
    {
        SearchFilter = new TSearchFilter();
    }
    public TSearchFilter SearchFilter { get; set; }
}
```

This way, the `QueryFilter` does not need to use a fake class.

Also, I've added a [`new()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) constraint to get rid of the `Activator.CreateInstance` call.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled. This structure better than me. And so, I convert my class like yours but in my method   `public static async Task<GridResult<List<T>>> GetGridResult<T, TSearchFilter>(this IQueryable<T> query, QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> queryFilter) where TSearchFilter : class
        {}` give me error like **TSearchFilter' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TSearchFilter' in the generic type or method 'QueryFilter<TSearchFilter>'**

Comment: That's because of the `new()` constraint. Try removing it and return to `Activator.CreateInstance` instead and see if it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: Where should I add `Activator.CreateInstance` in your class structure @ZoharPeled

Comment: replace `SearchFilter = new TSearchFilter();` with `SearchFilter = (TSearchFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSearchFilter));`

Comment: My code isn't building now. Because my method `public static async Task<GridResult<List<T>>> GetGridResult<T, TSearchFilter>(this IQueryable<T> query, QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> queryFilter) where TSearchFilter : class {}` want **QueryFilter<TSearchFilter>** . But, in your class structure we're sending **QueryFilter** @ZoharPeled

Comment: I think we need a broader background here - but what if you change the method signature to `public static async Task<GridResult<List<T>>> GetGridResult<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, QueryFilter queryFilter)`? Since now the generic class inherits the non-generic class this should be working fine with both

Comment: But now, how can you access `TsearchFilter` in your method? You're sending `QueryFilter` without `TsearchFilter` info.

Comment: Thanks @ ZoharPeled. I thought that there is a way that giving default parameter to generic class like this `public class QueryFilter : QueryFilter<typeof(Class)>{ }` . **But, I understood from your answer that there isn't any way in C#.** :(

Comment: You could do this like you've written in the question... It's a strange design but as you said, it's working.